# Assumptions in the equation Electric Potential ($V$)=$-\int\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential, potential-energy, conventions

Electric Potential: $V=-\int\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$

In this definition, do we have inbuilt assumption that test charge that we are moving is +ve and movement is against the field.

Because depending on the whether test charge is +ve or -ve and if the movement is against or in the direction of electric field, the signs can change.

I don’t see these assumptions explicitly mentioned anywhere. Feynman just mentions one of them i.e. movement is against the field.

Comment: Correct. A negative charge changes the sign. It is a standard sign convention.

Comment: what about work done.? is it also built in that work done is againt the field.?

Answer (score 0):

There are two definitions which one starts with.

A **positive** charge $q$ been chosen as the test charge to measure the force $\vec F$ in an electric field $\vec E$ and the work being done on a unit positive charge by an **external** force $\vec F_{\rm ext}$ (or negative work being done by the electric field) in the definition of potential $V$.

$\vec E = \displaystyle\lim_{q\to 0} \dfrac{\vec F}{q}$ and $V_2-V_1 = \displaystyle \int _1^2 \vec F_{\rm ext} \cdot \mathrm d\vec r = - \int _1^2 \vec E \cdot ~\mathrm d\vec r $

The choice of a positive charge is arbitrary but it is a convention which is used by all? Physicists.